# como Imprimir un archivo .docx desde python a una impresora usb

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenos dias quisiera saber como puedo mandar a imprimir un archivo .docx a una impresora usb conectada al pc.

este es un ejemplo que encontre en la web:

```
winword.exe /p "c:\marta.doc" /mFilePrintDefault /mFileExit
```

pero no me funciono

este es mi codigo python:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(['C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/root/Office16/WINWORD.EXE','/p','Comprobantes/17-08-2018210734_t_exe.docx','/mFilePrintDefault/mFileExit'])
```

Comment: ¿el comando `winword.exe /p "c:\marta.doc" /mFilePrintDefault /mFileExit` te funciono en la CMD?

Comment: el truco de python es ejecutar la linea que ejecutas en cmd si no te funciona la primera no te va a funcionar la segunda